# Citation style doesnt work

Tags: citing

I have following item in bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Koumou} KOUMOU, Gilles Boevie, et al.: 
\textit{Coherent diversification measures in portfolio theory: An axiomatic foundation}. CIRRELT, Centre interuniversitaire de recherche sur les r\'{e}seaux d'entreprise, la logistique et le transport = Interuniversity Research Centre on Enterprise Networks, Logistics and Transportation, 
2019.
\end{thebibliography}
```

and I want like to cite in style such as Koumou (2019), however, all i can get is (1) by \cite command. When I use \citet command, I obtain (author?)(1). Whats wrong and what can be done about it?

I use following commands

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether your document loads a citation management package such as `natbib` or `cite`.

Comment: See for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib for an introduction.

Comment: @Marijn that was the first source i looked up for an answer, but I was not able to make it work this way.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the `biblatex` tag as your bibliography setup would appear to be unrelated to anything the `biblatex` package does.

Comment: For `natbib` you need to use `\citet{name}` instead of `\cite{name}`, so with a `t` in the end.

Comment: @Marijn this command cannot print the authors name

Comment: Incidentally, since the publication in question has exactly two authors -- Gilles Boevi Koumou and George Dionne -- it would be customary to create a citation call-out of the form `Koumou and Dionne (2019)` rather than `Koumou et al. (2019)`. The `et al` name list truncation method is generally applied only if a piece has *three or more* authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building the formatted bibliography by hand, you must provide some structured information in the (so-far absent) optional argument of `\bibitem` so that `natbib` can create authoryear-style citation callouts. For instance, you must change

```
\bibitem{Koumou}
```

to

```
\bibitem[Koumou et~al.(2019)]{Koumou}
```

(Note: No space between `Koumou et~al.` and `(2019)`.)

This will enable `\citet` and `\citep` to generate citation call-outs of the desired variety.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\begin{document} 
\citet{Koumou}, \citep{Koumou}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Koumou et~al.(2019)]{Koumou} 
   \textsc{Koumou}, Gilles Boevie, et al.: \textit{Coherent diversification measures in portfolio theory: An axiomatic foundation}. CIRRELT, Centre Interuniversitaire de Recherche sur les Réseaux d'Entreprise, la Logistique et le Transport (Interuniversity Research Centre on Enterprise Networks, Logistics and Transportation), 2019.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```